# The nav bar doesn't clip to the top of iphone x

Tags: ios, swift

The Nav bar doesnt go to the top of the screen when rounding the edges on iphone x or up. Is there any way to fix this?

[IMAGE(WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE NOW)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXuT1.png)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default navigation bar has a background view which will be not generated when you apply custom operations on a layer.

[image: Debug View Hierarchy]

**Solution**

1. Create a view with a given color, radius corner and dimension
2. Convert the view to an image
3. Set the image view to a navigation bar *background* property

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: view.frame.width, height: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0)))
       v.backgroundColor = .red
       v.layer.cornerRadius = 20
       v.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
       v.clipsToBounds = true

       let i = image(with: v)!
       navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(i, for: .default)

   }

   func image(with view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
       defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
       if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
           view.layer.render(in: context)
           let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
           return image
       }
       return nil
   }
   ```

Comment: 'statusBarFrame' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xib` for add navigation bar for proper navigation  bar design. Which is compatible for all devices.

```
 var customNavView: Your_xib_File?

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationViewStup()   
    }

 func navigationViewStup(){
        customNavView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NavBar", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? NavBarView
        customNavView?.frame = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds)!
        customNavView?.tag = 1111
        customNavView?.btnVoice.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnVoicePressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(customNavView!)
    }
```

Or try this,

```
 func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
     return .topAttached
 }

 navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```